# Image scrambled when embedded into pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I'm having an issue when attempting to create a PDF with an image using iTextSharp. I'm adding the image to the top of the PDF like a masthead and then the rest of the PDF is HTML. The PDF generates fine and displays correctly when viewed in Edge, Chrome and Firefox. But, if you open it in IE or in Adobe Reader, the masthead is completely scrambled. The rest of the PDF (the HTML content) generates as expected in all browsers and programs. I've googled for days now trying to discover if anyone else has had this issue, but all I can find is text being garbled, not images. Below is the code I'm using to generate the image. Any ideas?

```
using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/kfa_masthead.jpg"));

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Left = 10f;
        image.Top = image.Height;
        image.ScaleAbsolute(560f, 58f);

        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
        {
            document.Open();
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            //Add the masthead
            document.Add(image);

            //Add the report information
            var html = CreateTable(profile);

            using (var xHtml = new StringReader(html))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, xHtml);
            }

            document.CloseDocument();
            document.Close();
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a PDF illustrating the issue.